# CSS or JS conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

I'm a novice so this may seem like a rather basic problem.

A html page has 4 html embedded audio players which looked as styled and worked fine. 
I then added a slide player called Fancy Box. The CSS and JS files are linked to separate folders than the CSS and JS files of the audio player.

The audio players continue to work fine however, the style attributes no longer show up, instead the browser’s audio player shows. Fancy Box works fine.

Is there a CSS or JS conflict of some sort?

Any advice is much appreciated in solving my dilemma. 
(Sorry for all my incompetence.)

Here is the HTML and Both CSS.

```css
/** audio player styles **/

.audio-player,
.audio-player div,
.audio-player h2,
.audio-player a,
.audio-player span,
.audio-player button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
div.audio-player {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.audio-player h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 10px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* play/pause control */

.mejs-controls .mejs-button button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
.mejs-controls .mejs-play button,
.mejs-controls .mejs-pause button {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  top: 32px;
  left: 7px;
  background: transparent url('playpause.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.mejs-controls .mejs-pause button {
  background-position: 0 -35px;
}
/* volume scrubber bar */

.mejs-controls div.mejs-horizontal-volume-slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  right: 85px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mejs-controls .mejs-horizontal-volume-slider .mejs-horizontal-volume-total {
  width: 85px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #212227;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.mejs-controls .mejs-horizontal-volume-slider .mejs-horizontal-volume-current {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 9px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  background: #c82530;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c82530 0%, #c82530 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c82530 0%, #c82530 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c82530 0%, #c82530 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c82530 0%, #c82530 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #c82530 0%, #c82530 100%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
/* time scrubber bar */

.mejs-controls div.mejs-time-rail {
  width: 160px;
}
.mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 12px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 55px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
}
.mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail .mejs-time-total {
  background: #565860;
  width: 160px !important;
  /* fixes display bug using jQuery 1.8+ */
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail .mejs-time-loaded {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: #7b7d82;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail .mejs-time-current {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00873d;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00873d 0%, #83bb63 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00873d 0%, #83bb63 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00873d 0%, #83bb63 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00873d 0%, #83bb63 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #00873d 0%, #83bb63 100%);
}
/* metallic sliders */

.mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail .mejs-time-handle {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 22px;
  top: -6px;
  background: url('handle-lg.png') no-repeat;
}
.mejs-controls .mejs-horizontal-volume-slider .mejs-horizontal-volume-handle {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 14px;
  top: -1px;
  background: url('handle-sm.png') no-repeat;
}
/* time progress tooltip */

.mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail .mejs-time-float {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 33px;
  height: 23px;
  top: -26px;
  margin-left: -17px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('time-box.png');
}
.mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail .mejs-time-float-current {
  width: 33px;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 4px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}
/** clearfix **/

.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}
html[xmlns] .clearfix {
  display: block;
}
* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Paul Minotto: Music</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #000;
}
a:link {
 color: #00873d;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
 color: #cc3333;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a {
 font-size: 14px;
}
a:hover {
 color: #cc3333;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 36px;
}
-->
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
function MM_callJS(jsStr) { //v2.0
  return eval(jsStr)
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
//-->
</script>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.green {color: #11772E;
}
.red {color: #cc3333;
}
#rcorners { border-radius: 45%;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    padding: 0px; 
    width: 700px;
    height: 130px;    
}
.color {
 color: #FFF;
}
</style>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/styles.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>

   
  <title>slideShow</title>

 <!-- Add jQuery library -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    
 <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
 });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
  prevEffect : 'none',
  nextEffect : 'none',
  helpers : {
   title : {
    type: 'outside'
   },
   thumbs : {
    width : 50,
    height : 50
   }
  }
   });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

```css
CSS for slide show player.
/*! fancyBox v2.1.5 fancyapps.com | fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license */
.fancybox-wrap,
.fancybox-skin,
.fancybox-outer,
.fancybox-inner,
.fancybox-image,
.fancybox-wrap iframe,
.fancybox-wrap object,
.fancybox-nav,
.fancybox-nav span,
.fancybox-tmp
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: none;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.fancybox-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 8020;
}

.fancybox-skin {
 position: relative;
 background: #f9f9f9;
 color: #444;
 text-shadow: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
         border-radius: 4px;
}

.fancybox-opened {
 z-index: 8030;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
         box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner {
 position: relative;
}

.fancybox-inner {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-inner {
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.fancybox-error {
 color: #444;
 font: 14px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-image, .fancybox-iframe {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.fancybox-image {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}

#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
 background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
}

#fancybox-loading {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -22px;
 margin-left: -22px;
 background-position: 0 -108px;
 opacity: 0.8;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 8060;
}

#fancybox-loading div {
 width: 44px;
 height: 44px;
 background: url('fancybox_loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

.fancybox-close {
 position: absolute;
 top: -18px;
 right: -18px;
 width: 36px;
 height: 36px;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-nav {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 width: 40%;
 height: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: transparent url('blank.gif'); /* helps IE */
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-prev {
 left: 0;
}

.fancybox-next {
 right: 0;
}

.fancybox-nav span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: 36px;
 height: 34px;
 margin-top: -18px;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 8040;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.fancybox-prev span {
 left: 10px;
 background-position: 0 -36px;
}

.fancybox-next span {
 right: 10px;
 background-position: 0 -72px;
}

.fancybox-nav:hover span {
 visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-tmp {
 position: absolute;
 top: -99999px;
 left: -99999px;
 visibility: hidden;
 max-width: 99999px;
 max-height: 99999px;
 overflow: visible !important;
}

/* Overlay helper */

.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: auto;
}

.fancybox-lock body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.fancybox-lock-test {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

.fancybox-overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: none;
 z-index: 8010;
 background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}

.fancybox-overlay-fixed {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
 overflow: auto;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Title helper */

.fancybox-title {
 visibility: hidden;
 font: normal 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: none;
 z-index: 8050;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {
 visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 50%;
 margin-bottom: -35px;
 z-index: 8050;
 text-align: center;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap .child {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: -100%;
 padding: 2px 20px;
 background: transparent; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
         border-radius: 15px;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #222;
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 24px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-title-outside-wrap {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 10px;
 color: #FFF;
}

.fancybox-title-inside-wrap {
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.fancybox-title-over-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0px;
 background: #000;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/*Retina graphics!*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){

 #fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
  background-image: url('fancybox_sprite@2x.png');
  background-size: 44px 152px; /*The size of the normal image, half the size of the hi-res image*/
 }

 #fancybox-loading div {
  background-image: url('fancybox_loading@2x.gif');
  background-size: 24px 24px; /*The size of the normal image, half the size of the hi-res image*/
 }
```

Comment: You have a line break in two of your script's `src` attribute values. Could be that. Also in the `href` for the last `link`.

Comment: click f12 or bring up developer tool. Then you can see why these attribute is not showing up when you click at the individual tag.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions.  
Just to clarify, the audio players were being styled by the attributes in the CSS.  It was only when i added the code for the slide player from <title>slideShow</title>down that affected the audio player style.  So since everything is working prior to that, the code for the slide Show is causing some sort of conflict.

Comment: One other thing i noticed.  By placing the code for the audio player after the Slide Show, the CSS for the audio players show up, but the Slide Show does not play.

Comment: @Paolo You're loading two different versions of jquery 1.10.2 and 1.10.1. Only load one.

Comment: Thank you Alejalapeno.  I followed your suggestion only loading 1.10.2 but to no avail.  Still the same problem.

Comment: @Paolo Put together a codepen.io or live example. Your code is incomplete and we can't even tell what your css is. You're just posting the `<link>` which can only tell so much.

Comment: here is the page: [link] http://www.minotto.design/musica/musica.html
Thank you.

Comment: I can send both CSS.  Is there an easier way to do it instead of having to format it in the editing window on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Ok here are both CSS.  Sorry for being such an idiot about all this.  It's all new to me - i'm drowning in my incompetence.